# LoginView in Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a loginview with using xamarin.form. I have implemented the following code into my project, however, once I run, it does not display anything on the view.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WebComponents
{   
    public partial class LoginView : ContentPage
    {   
        public LoginView ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();


            var profilePage = new ContentPage {
                Title = "Profile",
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    Spacing = 20,
                    Padding = 50,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Entry { Placeholder = "Username" },
                        new Entry { Placeholder = "Password", IsPassword = true },
                        new Button { Text = "Login", TextColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("77D065") }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoginView is a subclass of ContentPage - you are creating another ContentPage, profilePage, but not doing anything with it.  Try this instead:

```
   Entry username;
   Entry password;
   Button button;

   public LoginView ()
   {
        InitializeComponent ();

        Title = "Profile";

        Content = new StackLayout {
                Spacing = 20,
                Padding = 50,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    (username = new Entry { Placeholder = "Username" }),
                    (password = new Entry { Placeholder = "Password", IsPassword = true }),
                    (button = new Button { Text = "Login", TextColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("77D065") })
                }
            }
        };

        button.Clicked += Login;
    }

    public void Login(object sender, EventArgs ea) 
    {
        // check values of username and password here
    }
```

Comment: @ Jason, thanks a lot it works. I will mark your answer once SOF allows me in couple of minutes.

Comment: How do we check username and password in this context?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. How to write username on application output? Console.WriteLine does not work. Console.WriteLine(username);

Comment: Nevermind, System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(username);

Comment: Hello Jason, please see my updated question based on your answer. I am getting an error.

Comment: Apparently you can't assign an event handler in an initializer.  See my new edit.

Comment: any idea for the following question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876277/image-xamarin-form