# Image- Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a login page and now I want to add a header image; however, image does not show up on the view.

```
    public LoginView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        Title= "Login";

        Content = new StackLayout {
            Spacing = 20,
            Padding = 50,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Image {Source="headerImage.jpg"},
                (username = new Entry { Placeholder = "Username" }),
                (password = new Entry { Placeholder = "Password", IsPassword = true }),
                (button=new Button { Text = "Login", TextColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex ("77D065")})
            }
        };

        button.Clicked += Login;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images need to be placed in the platform projects (iOS, Android, etc) not the shared Forms project.  See [Working with Images](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) for details.

"Images can be shared across platforms with Xamarin.Forms, they can be loaded specifically for each platform, or they can be downloaded for display."

Comment: You're right Jason.It worked once I moved from form project to iOS, then it grabs the image. Interesting.

Comment: Hello Jason, do u have any idea about the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026322/map-annotation-disclosure-indicator-xamarin-form