# Map Annotation Disclosure Indicator - Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Form platform to use Map feature in my application. I could able to add an annotation on the map. However, I would like to know is there a way to add disclosure indicator on annotation that enables user to tap to go to DetailViewController.

```
        using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

        Map map;
        Title= "MapView";

        map = new Map { 
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        map.Pins.Add(new Pin {
            Position = new Position(29.7,-95.0177232),
            Label = "Boardwalk"
        });
```

[image]

I want something similar to the following screnshot.

[image]

Comment: Do you have ot use exactly the 'Xamarin.Forms Maps' lib? If not, I suggest you to use https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps - amay077 Google maps. It's quite easy to use and it has a lot of features that might help you.

Comment: oops, i didn't see the year of the question ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible to provide your own views in the current **Xamarin.Forms** **Maps** component (*v1.2.3x*) as it is very locked down.

**Update 1:-**

Unfortunately not.  This is a requested feature for **Xamarin.Forms**, as of October 24 [here](http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions/suggestions/6607194-onclick-listener-for-pin-markers-and-support-for-c).

The only way around at present would be to create your own custom renderer.

Comment: Hello Pete, is it possible to go detailviewcontroller by tapping annotationview ? In other words, in my example, I want user to tap on "BoardWalk" to detailViewcontroller

Comment: I've updated my answer (See *Update 1*).  Also I sent you an email.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete for the update, It is sad to know the fact. Do you have any sample, suggest useful link of creating custom renderer?