# Xamarin local image from file or resources

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I cannot get my images to show up in Android at all.  I have tried with ImageSource.FromFile and ImageSource.FromResource.

I have read "Working with Images" several times and just don't see what I am doing wrong.

From File Example

```
        var myImage = new Image() {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("backdrop.jpg")
        };

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout();

        layout.Children.Add(myImage,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));

        Content = layout;
```

[image]

The Build Action is set to: AndroidResource

I always get the NullReference exception with this path

[image]

FromResource example

```
        var myImage = new Image()
        {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource("TTMD_Mobile.Droid.backdrop.jpg")
        };

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout();

        layout.Children.Add(myImage,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));

        Content = layout;
```

The Build Action is set to: Embedded Resource

With the FromResource I don't get any exception, just the image doesn't show.

I am fairly new to Xamarin and Android development, my apologies if this has been addressed, I couldn't find a working solution.

EDIT: I do not believe this is a duplicate of that question, I have my images in their correct locations I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image- Xamarin.Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876277/image-xamarin-form)

Comment: @SushiHangover, this is not a duplicate of that... I have my images in their correct locations (or so I believe I do per the "working with images" documentation).

Comment: I would suggest deleting all `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders in your Forms and Android projects and then completely delete the app from the device. Rebuild the solution and try again. I have found that images do not get copied over if the app is already installed on the device.

Comment: Thanks @hvaughan3, still no luck.  It seems like this should be easy :-(

Answer (score 3):

Create images folder in Xamarin forms project and then add Image to that folder. 
In properties for the image, set "Build Action" to "Embedded resource"

For ex: My project name is XTest.
Path to image is: XTest/images/pic.jpg

[image: Solution explorer showing path]

In you cs file you can now use it like this.

```
    imgLocal.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("XTest.images.pic.jpg");
```